# Checking user role in settings repository (typescript, aurelia)

Tags: typescript, authentication, npm, aurelia

I'm doing some navigation with authorization. I did something like this

```
run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next) : Promise<any> {

    let requiredRoles = navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions()
                        .map(i => i.config.settings.roles)[0];

    toastr.success('TEST1');

    let isUserInRole = requiredRoles?   
        requiredRoles.some(r => r === this.userIdentity.role) : true;

    toastr.success('TEST2');//LINE IT`S NOT EXECUTED

    return isUserInRole? next() : next.cancel(new Redirect('users/login'));    
}
```

**requiredRoles** - I have checked and it's return me value

Into line `r => r === this.userIdentity.role` In my Visual Code I have message like: `Parameter 'r' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.ts(7044)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you can do is casting the `.roles)[0]` to string (I guess from the look of your code)

```
run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next) : Promise<any> {

    let requiredRoles = navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions()
                        .map(i => i.config.settings.roles)[0] as string;
  ...  
}
```

Edit: if roles are an array of string, then your code should be like this

```
run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next) : Promise<any> {

    let requiredRoles = navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions()
                        .map(i => i.config.settings.roles)[0] as string[];
  ...  
}
```

Doing that should make the issue go away.

Comment: after changes I got this: `Property 'some' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)`